# How is/can saving a username/password in a web browser specifically be a threat for CSRF attacks?

Tags: csrf

In a recent online certification training course, the instructor specifically listed "Do not save username/password in the browser" as a CSRF mitigation strategy (among others).

[image: Screenshot]

I understand why storing passwords on a browser can be a bad idea (because in essence, you're now trusting the browser to be a secure password manager) but how would this specifically aid a bad actor in a CSRF attack?

Comment: I imagine the logic is lets say the user credentials are saved as a cookie, it is vulnerable to CSRF since the attacker can make a rouge POST request from their domain and leverage your credentials cookie as authentication to damage that users data on the web site/app.

Comment: Huh, it looks like my interpretation that they meant "dont use remember me" was wrong. I have deleted my answer. This is a myserty to me and I hope you get a good answer!

Comment: While it might be good advice, it doesn't have anything to do with CSRF.

Comment: I'd say it's actively bad advice, because using your browser's password manager encourages unique and longer passwords and helps you notice phishing attacks (since you can notice something is strange when your login info isn't autofilled).